# Declare a mixin as a type instead of as a variable

Tags: typescript

Here's the minimum code that demonstrates what I mean.

```js
class Foo {
    public bar = "baz"
}

type Constructable<T> = {
    new (...args: any[]): T
}

interface Bar {
    sayHello(): void
}

function extend<T>(BaseClass: Constructable<T>): Constructable<T & Bar> {
    return class extends (BaseClass as Constructable<any>) {
        sayHello(): void {
            console.log("Hello!")
        }
    } as Constructable<T & Bar>
}

const FooBar = extend(Foo)
const fooBar = new FooBar()

fooBar.sayHello()
```

All of that code works fine except that I wish I could write this:

```js
const fooBar: FooBar = new FooBar()
```

But I can't, because `FooBar` is a value, not a type. Now I'm aware that I can write this:

```js
const FooBar = extend(Foo)
type FooBar = Foo & Bar
const fooBar: FooBar = new FooBar()
```

But I would prefer to rewrite the above it such that TS just immediately understands that `FooBar` is both a value *and* a type. Something like `class FooBar = extend(Foo)` except valid.

[Here's a little playground that you can play around with.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNHmAE7QC80ARGQF62oC+qqALgJ5YCm0AYXgA7CB3I5gHMAV4AeACoA+ainSZhvAO7QAFADpDFAOYQAXNDDCuAbQC6ASgsLW7QsI69yAMzDB+AEIUapjQEGBcABK8ICDwuk7QAG7whAAmrqjeOMJShCLQvAAensJpikq6QRC8AuBQFkKi4pLSshWJTWISUjIg8grQAGTQQeQqaKHkvBw45MLQoJAwxaVpMFWQtfUwkIIi3a198lZcSg4hoZjhUTFxCRYp6ZdXV8AH8P36cca6tNGxeAAQloDnUrzYoRYlhgXRavXagxGYyUmXezTgiDGqlWvDKugQ8DB6LE0G8WOCNE0OkJYwS7HJ8DG+huAPuYKAA)

Answer (score 0):

Types exists only at compile time in typescript.

`const FooBar` is a runtime value, you will not be able to use that at a the place of type.

You will have to derive expected type from `FooBar` const.

All you can do is, instead of manually creating this type `type FooBar = Foo & Bar`, you can derive it using below shown `TypeOf` utility.

This is the common pattern used in libraries like [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/), [runtype](https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes) etc.

```js
type TypeOf<T> = T extends Constructable<infer U> ? U : never
const FooBar = extend(Foo)
type FooBar = TypeOf<typeof FooBar>
// inferred type of FooBar is Foo & Bar
```

Comment: Hmmm, damn, so I will always need to add that extra line of code? I can't somehow make the function return the type declaration as well?

Comment: No, you cant do that. We are using io-ts, and you can see this pattern here:
https://github.com/tmtsoftware/esw-ts/blob/master/lib/src/models/params/Key.ts#L100

Comment: A "function returning a type declaration" makes no sense because functions are executed at runtime and types only exist at compile time.